# Pandas not able to read specific Excel sheet instead it is reading first sheet of the workbbok

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to access the first sheet of the excel file. How can I do this? Below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'S:\hotel pan Management\zero Material\Test run\Indepedent Run_2020\Return.Xlsx',sheet_names='FactorRtn')

print(df)
```

Comment: What output did you receive? Is it an error message? If yes, please paste the error message here for others to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing `sheet_names` with `sheet_name` should do it.